# difficult with radio button control in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am controlling the radio buttons in my application with Javascript. The number of radio buttons are not always the same. I have the problem when the radio button is only one. The function is:

```
function ChangeDiv() {
    var i;
    var j;

    for (i=0; i<document.doc_copy.rad.length; i++) {
        if (document.doc_copy.rad[i].checked) {
            document.getElementById(document.doc_copy.rad[i].value).style.display='block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(document.doc_copy.rad[i].value).style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
```

If the radio button is checked I show a HTML div that is hidden. The problem is that when I have only one radio button, the bucle for is not executed and the hidden div is not shown.

Comment: Are you incrementing before the function runs? Consider not using a radio button if there's only one. That scenario violates expected use standards.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: what type of object is that .rad? How are you assigning it? Just a hunch, but you're probably better off using a selector and dumping those radios into a variable `var rad = $("#myRadios");` Assigning it to the document object could get you in some trouble, depending on how complex your page gets.

Comment: @ginman: what gives you the idea that the OP's using, or even willing to use, jQuery?

Comment: `document.getElementById("myRadios");`? If i were actually answering the question, i guess i would make it idiot proof.

Comment: I dont know previously the number of radio buttons because it depends of the number of documents my application find. I have no problems when the numbers of radiobuttons is more than 1. Rad is the name of the radiobutton, an array of radiobuttons. The think i dont understand is why when there are for example 2 radio buttons, there are no problems, but with one i cant execute it

Answer (score 0):

After reading again, I believe I noticed something in the code. You check document.doc_copy.rad.length (radio buttons I suppose) but when you write the code to display the DIV, you use this document.getElementById(document.doc_copy.rad[i].value).style.display. I think instead of rad[i] you should have something else related to the div you want to hide/display.

---

Thanks to Barmar I realized my answer is wrong.

<strike>When you have only one radio button, your index is 0. That means that the FOR statement will not be executed at all.</strike>

You need to use a DO...WHILE which ensures you will have one execution no matter what.

```
function ChangeDiv(){   var i;  var j;      i = 0;  do {        if(document.doc_copy.rad[i].checked){           document.getElementById(document.doc_copy.rad[i].value).style.display='block';      }else{          document.getElementById(document.doc_copy.rad[i].value).style.display='none';       }   i++;    } while(i<=document.doc_copy.rad.length);
}
```

Comment: or use a $.each if using jquery

Comment: Why won't his `for` statement be executed? `.length` should be 1, and `0 < 1` is true.

Comment: The same, the first if is not executed

Comment: @Barmar - You are right! I thought of the index and not of the length.